# Entity Framework 6 table with many foreign keys each pointing to different tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have Country, City, Region and "Account Address" tables.

I want to create foreign key columns in "Account Address" pointing to Country, City, Region tables.

I have this code but it throws an error on creating database

> The property \u0027Account_Id\u0027 cannot be configured as a
>   navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the
>   property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection
>   properties the type must implement

```
After New Edit

public class Cities
{
    [Key]
    public int City_Id { get; set; }
    public string City_name { get; set; }
    public int Country_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Country_Id")]
    public Countries countries { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    [Key]
    public int Region_Id { get; set; }
    public string Region_name { get; set; }
    public int City_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("City_Id")]
    public Countries countries { get; set; }
}

public class Accounts
{
    [Key]
    public int Account_Id { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public int Cell_phone { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public int? estate_office_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("estate_office_Id")]
    public Estate_office estate_office { get; set; }

    public List<Ads> ads { get; set; }
}

public class Account_address
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Account_Id"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Account_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Country_Id"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Country_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("City_Id"), Column(Order = 2)]
    public int City_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Region_Id"), Column(Order = 3)]
    public int Region_Id { get; set; }

    public Accounts accounts { get; set; }
    public Countries countries { get; set; }
    public Cities cities { get; set; }
    public Region region { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `public` properties as shown below on the `Account_address` class.Then only EF will know how to map those navigation properties correctly.

```
  public class Account_address
   {
    ......
    ......


    public  Accounts accounts { get; set; } //like this
    public  Countries countries { get; set; } //like this
    public  Cities cities { get; set; } //like this
    public  Region region { get; set; } //like this
  }
```

**Update :**

Hence you're not using singular naming convention for the classes,you have encountered this issue.Either you have to change the name of classes as singular or need to change the navigational property names a shown below.You have to do this for all the places.Here I have shown only for the `Accounts` class related navigational property.

```
    [ForeignKey("Accounts_Id"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Accounts_Id { get; set; }
```

**My Advice** is to follow the **basic naming conventions**.Then you can avoid lot of above kind of weird errors.

Comment: I got the same Error

Comment: public class Accounts
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public int Cell_phone { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public int? estate_office_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("estate_office_Id")]
        public Estate_office estate_office { get; set; }
        public List<Ads> ads { get; set; }
    }

Comment: can you read above code ? please put that on your original post.

Comment: I got that error "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint \u0027FK_dbo.Cities_dbo.Countries_Country_Id\u0027 on table \u0027Cities\u0027 may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.\r\nCould not create constraint"

Comment: can you update your final code base which you're using now ?

Comment: your `Region` class FK is also wrong.here `[ForeignKey("City_Id")]
    public Countries countries { get; set; }` ?

Comment: I Updated the Post , And I still Get the first error

Comment: I cannot see the modification which i have mentioned on **Update** section ? Why ?

Comment: I did it in "After New Edit" I named the navigational property Like the primary key like in like [ForeignKey("Country_Id"), Column(Order = 1)]

Comment: Well then , I Found a better Design  I will Connect Only the Region as a navigational property then the Region Will Be connected automatically to the Table Above

Comment: Now no issues or what ?

Comment: I will Make It One ForeignKey in the table so no issues  , thank you

Comment: OK,Grate :) Hope you can accept the answer then no ? see how to do that : http://stackoverflow.com/tour